# How to rearrange array by array key?

Tags: php, arrays

I am just trying to rearray my array for proper looping.
I feel respect who can help me out to solve this issue.

```
My input array is:-

array(
'text'=>array('icon_title_1'=>'Test 1','icon_title_2'=>'Test 2'),
'image'=>array('icon_file_1',='test.jpg','icon_file_2'=>'test2.jpg')
 )

 My Required output array is:-

 array(
     0=>array(
         'text'=>'Test 1'
         'image'=>'test.jpg'    
     ),
     1=>array(
         'text'=>'Test 2'
         'image'=>'test2.jpg'   
     )
  );
```

Comment: What is your input array? What code are you currently using to get your output array?

Comment: Kindly post your input array also.

Comment: @nick I am just use foreach loop to to get my required array.

Comment: My input array is same as output array.

Comment: But what is your input data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is the final format of your input. You can use `array_map`

**Solution**

```
$data = array(
    'text'=>array('icon_title_1' =>'Test 1','icon_title_2'=>'Test 2'),
    'image'=>array('icon_file_1' => 'test.jpg','icon_file_2'=>'test2.jpg')
);

$func = function($text, $image){
    return  [
            'text' => $text,
            'image' => $image
        ];
};
var_dump(array_map($func, $data['text'], $data['image']));
```

**Output**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["text"]=>
    string(6) "Test 1"
    ["image"]=>
    string(8) "test.jpg"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["text"]=>
    string(6) "Test 2"
    ["image"]=>
    string(9) "test2.jpg"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your given input format you can use the below code to get your result, Assuming the inner array key format like icon_title_1,icon_title_2,icon_title_3 etc.. and icon_file_1,icon_file_2 etc..

```
$input = array(
'text'=>array(
                'icon_title_1'=>'Test 1',
                'icon_title_2'=>'Test 2'),
'image'=>array(
                'icon_file_1'=>'test.jpg',
                'icon_file_2'=>'test2.jpg')
);
$output = array();
$index = 0;
foreach($input  as $key => $value){
 foreach($value as $k => $v){
     $indexPart = explode("_",$k);
     $index = $indexPart[count($indexPart)-1];
     $output[$index][$key] = $v;
 }
}

print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can transform your array with a simple nested `foreach` loop:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $arr) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($arr as $v) {
        $result[$i++][$key] = $v;
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [text] => Test 1
            [image] => test.jpg
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [text] => Test 2
            [image] => test2.jpg
    )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/57tAO)

Comment: @PawanDongol no worries. I hope it's useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use can also use **foreach** loop :

```
 $newarray = array();
    foreach ($array as $k => $arr) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($arr as $ar) {
            $newarray[$i++][$k] = $ar;
        }
    }
    print_r($newarray);
```